# Possible to retrieve the SQL table including foreign key substituted to serialized data?

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, group-by

(copied from the comment)

> I use mysql 5.7 aws aurora. – Gurebu Bokofu

---

Suppose that the entities like products:

```
product
--------
id | name
1  | hoge
2  | fuga
```

has tags:

```
tag
---------
id | name
11 | tag1
22 | tag2
```

To know, is being tag used by product or now, mapping table using:

```
map_product_tag
product_id | tag_id
1          | 11           <- product with ID 1 using tag with ID 11
1          | 22           <- product with ID 1 using tag with ID 22
2          | 22           <- product with ID 1 using tag with ID 22
```

I want to retrieve the below result by SQL request:

```
product_id | tags
             // ↓ all tags those product with ID 1 using
1          | [{ "tagId": 11, "tagName": "tag1"}, { "tagId": 22, "tagName": "tag2"}]     
             // ↓ all tags those product with ID 2 using
2          | [{ "tagId": 22, "tagName": "tag2"}]
```

If it's possible, please teach me the appropriate syntax.

My database is MySQL.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are running: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Comment: @GMB, I tagged my question.

Comment: *I want to retrieve the below result by SQL request:* Your JSON is NOT valid. `{}` brackets means that this is object, not array, which is defined as "An object is an unordered set of **name/value pairs**".

Comment: @Akina, I'll edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
-- MySQL 8+ specific
select product.id product_id,
       json_arrayagg(json_object('tag_id', tag.id, 'tag_name', tag.name)) 
from map_product_tag
join product on map_product_tag.product_id = product.id
join tag on map_product_tag.tag_id = tag.id
group by product_id;
```

```sql
-- MySQL 5+ compatible
select product.id product_id,
       CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(json_object('tag_id', tag.id, 'tag_name', tag.name)), ']')
from map_product_tag
join product on map_product_tag.product_id = product.id
join tag on map_product_tag.tag_id = tag.id
group by product_id;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=288269087a9cc6f242a603aa5ca2c6b2)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, I got error `ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION myDataBase.json_arrayagg does not exist`. Invalid version? I use `mysql 5.7 aws aurora`.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu Why you have not specified your version previously if it is not the most recent?